# Encoding error when writing in gml file

Tags: python-2.7, encoding, networkx

In one of my previous posts I had a problem with reading and writing strings that are in a language different from English. The problem was in the encoding of my system. **ton1c** mentioned that writing the strings in a txt is fine and indeed it is! Now I am trying to pass these string in a gml file and I am encountering a problem with the encoding again. Here is the code and the results.

```
import urllib2
import BeautifulSoup
import networkx as nx

url = 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/zhongwen/simp/'

page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read().decode("utf-8")
dom =  BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(page)

data = dom.findAll('meta', {'name' : 'keywords'})
data = data.encode("utf-8")
datalist = data.split(',')

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_node( "name", Strings = datalist );
```

It returns

```
File "C:\...\name.py", line 23, in <module> nx.write_gml(G, 'Gname')
File "<string>", line 2, in write_gml
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\networkx\utils\decorators.py", line 263, in _open_file
   result = func(*new_args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\networkx\readwrite\gml.py", line 392, in write_gml
   path.write(line.encode('latin-1'))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 13: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Any suggestions? I would like also to mention that in the site of networkx it mentions *GML specifications indicate that the file should only use 7bit ASCII text encoding.iso8859-1 (latin-1).* (http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.readwrite.gml.write_gml.html)

PS: Please any suggestion in Python 2.7 compatibility please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just do the following:

```
import urllib2
import BeautifulSoup
import networkx as nx

url = 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/zhongwen/simp/'

page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read().decode("latin-1")
dom =  BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(page)

data = dom.findAll('meta', {'name' : 'keywords'})
data = data[0]['content'].encode("latin-1")
#datalist = data.split(',')

with open("tags.txt", "w") as text_file:
    text_file.write("%s"%data)

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_node( "name", Strings = data.decode("latin-1") );
nx.write_gml(G,"test.gml")

graph [
  node [
    id 0
    label "name"
    Strings "BBC中文网，主页，国际新闻，中国新闻，台湾新闻，香港新闻，英国新闻，信息，财经，科技，卫生 互动，多媒体，视频，音频，图辑，bbcchinese.com, homepage, world news, China news, uk news, hong kong, taiwan, sci-tech, business, interactive, forum"
  ]
]
```